# Regional Persistent Disks on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a scenario where I've got a containerized app with a single config file that I need to store outside of the container for relatively infrequent read/write access. A simple way to do this is to use a regional persistent disk which I'd then mount on my pod using a PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim.

However, persistent disks can only replicate data between two zones. Our GKE's run on at least three zones and have automated maintenance enabled so the nodes could float between zones. If the pod starts up on a node in one of the zones that doesn't match where the persistent disk is stored, it'll just hang.

How does GKE support this? Am I missing something obvious or is the only way to make failover between all zones and nodes in a region to use a managed storage service like FileStore or GCSFuse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case, I'd suggest using GCS Fuse (we will actually be including this with GKE soon so you won't need to install the CSI driver yourself).  Filestore is a good option as well, but the min size in 1TB.

To answer the question on regional PD, your pod/container would be limited to the two zones used by the regional PD.